# How can I upgrade Python version and packages in pyenv virtualenv?

Tags: python, virtualenv, pyenv

I used `pyenv`, `pyenv-virtualenv` for managing python virtual environment.

I have a project working in `Python 3.4` virtual environment.

So all installed packages(`pandas`, `numpy` etc) are not newest version.

What I want to do is to upgrade `Python` version from 3.4 to 3.6 as well as upgrade other package version to higher one.

How can I do this easily?

Comment: maybe create a new virtual environment?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `pip freeze > requirements.txt` to save a list of installed packages.

Create a new venv with python 3.6.

Install saved packages with `pip install -r requirements.txt`. When pip finds a universal wheel in its cache it installs the package from the cache. Other packages will be downloaded, cached, built and installed.

Comment: This is half the solution so I don't understand why it's chosen as the solution for this post. Not only do you have to save your requirements, but you have to nuke your old virtual env, create a new one with the new python version and then restore your requirements! @cglacet has the right answer above

Answer (score 42):

Here is how you can switch to `3.9.0` for a given virtual environement `venv-name`:

```bash
pip freeze > requirements-lock.txt
pyenv virtualenv-delete venv-name
pyenv install -s 3.9.0
pyenv virtualenv 3.9.0 venv-name
pyenv activate venv-name
pip install -r requirements-lock.txt
```

Once everything works correctly you can safely remove the temporary requirements *lock file*:

```bash
rm requirements-lock.txt
```

Note that using `pip freeze > requirements.txt` is **usually not a good idea** as this file is often used to handle your package requirements ([not necessarily](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files) `pip freeze` output). It's better to use a different (temporary) file just to be safe.

Comment: If you don't have 3.9.0 install on your system, you'll have to do run `pyenv install -v 3.9.0` before you create the new virtualenv.

Comment: You are right, I'll add that line just in case

Comment: You also need to activate the virtual environment by running `pyenv activate venv-name` before `pip install -r requirements-lock.txt`.

Answer (score 7):

OP asked to upgrade the packages alongside Python. No other answers address the upgrade of packages. Lock files are not the answer here.

---

Save your packages to a requirements file **without the version**.

```
pip freeze | cut -d"=" -f1 > requirements-to-upgrade.txt
```

Delete your environment, create a new one with the upgraded Python version, then install the requirements file.

```
pyenv virtualenv-delete venv-name
pyenv virtualenv 3.6.8 venv-name
pip install -r requirements-to-upgrade.txt
```

The dependency resolver in pip should try to find the latest package. This assumes you have the upgrade Python version installed (e.g., `pyenv install 3.6.8`).

Answer (score -4):

If you use anaconda, just type

conda install python==$pythonversion$